# Python + Selenium: Page object pattern: Need help to figure out why it doesn't see an attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a Python + Selenium newbie. Today started learning about the [Page Object Pattern](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/) and faced this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "logintest.py", line 17, in test_login
login_page.login()
File "D:\Tests\page object pattern\loginpage.py", line 19, in login
BasePage.fill_the_form(loginform, email)
NameError: name 'loginform' is not defined
```

I don't know why it throws it, because loginform **is** defined.

#### Base page

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from selenium import webdriver

class BasePage(object):

     def __init__(self, driver):
     self.driver = driver

     @abstractmethod
     def _validate_page(self, driver):
         return

     def fill_the_form(self, locator, value):
         form = self.driver.find_element(locator)
         self.form.clear()
         self.form.send_keys(value)

    def go_to(self, locator):
         self.driver.find_element(locator)
         self.driver.click()
```

#### Login page

```
from base import BasePage
from homepage import HomePage
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
class LoginPage(BasePage):

     email = 'test@test.net'
     password = 'test'
     loginform = (By.ID, 'email')
     passwordform = (By.ID, 'password')
     button = (By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")

     def __init__(self, driver):
         super(LoginPage, self).__init__(driver)


     def _validate_page(self, driver):
         assert 'Login' in driver.title()

     def login(self):
         BasePage.fill_the_form(loginform, email)
         BasePage.fill_the_form(passwordform, password)
         BasePage.go_to(button)
```

#### Base test

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 import unittest
 class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def setUp(self):
         self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
         self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
         self.driver.get('https://testtest.com/')
     def tearDown(self):
         self.driver.quit()
```

And finally my test:

```
 import unittest
 from basetest import BaseTest
 from base import BasePage
 from loginpage import LoginPage

 class logintest(BaseTest):

      def test_login(self):

           login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
           login_page.login()


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main(verbosity = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables `email`, `password`, `loginform`, etc. are static. To access them, use `LoginPage.loginform`:

```
def login(self):
     BasePage.fill_the_form(LoginPage.loginform, LoginPage.email)
     BasePage.fill_the_form(LoginPage.passwordform, LoginPage.password)
     BasePage.go_to(LoginPage.button)
```

Or declare them in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, driver):
    super(LoginPage, self).__init__(driver)
    self.email = 'test@test.net'
    self.password = 'test'
    self.loginform = (By.ID, 'email')
    self.passwordform = (By.ID, 'password')
    self.button = (By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Log In')]")
```

Comment: thx, @Guy It helped. But I faced a new problem:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "logintest.py", line 13, in test_login
    login_page.login()
    File "D:\Tests\page object pattern\loginpage.py", line 20, in login
    BasePage.fill_the_form(LoginPage.loginform, LoginPage.email)
    TypeError: fill_the_form() missing 1 required positional argument:     'value'`

Comment: @RomanMakowski Try `super(LoginPage, self).fill_the_form(LoginPage.loginform, LoginPage.email)`

Comment: Now the traceback is even bigger:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logintest.py", line 13, in test_login
    login_page.login()
  File "D:\Tests\page object pattern\loginpage.py", line 20, in login
    super(LoginPage, self).fill_the_form(LoginPage.loginform, LoginPage.email)
  File "D:\Tests\page object pattern\base.py", line 14, in fill_the_form
    form = self.driver.find_element(locator)
 **some selenium stuff**
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Cound not convert strategy to string

Comment: @RomanMakowski Try double brackets around the locators `loginform = ((By.ID, 'email'))`

Comment: the same exception